# I get an error compiling this struct program in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct lottery {
    int aa;
    struct date date1;
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int n3;
    int n4;
    int n5;
    int joker;
};

void load(struct lottery *array) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("as.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("00000\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d;%d/%d/%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d", &array[i].aa, &array[i].date1.day, &array[i].date1.month, &array[i].date1.year, &array[i].n1, &array[i].n2, &array[i].n3, &array[i].n4, &array[i].n5, &array[i].joker);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
    }
    array = (struct lottery*)realloc(array, i * sizeof(struct lottery));
    //  printf("%d;%d/%d/%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d", array[0].aa, array[0].date1.day, array[0].date1.month, array[0].date1.year, array[0].n1, array[0].n2, array[0].n3, array[0].n4, array[0].n5, array[0].joker);
 }

int main() {
    struct lottery *array;
    array = (struct lottery *)malloc(4 * sizeof(struct lottery));
    // printf("%d", sizeof(struct lottery));
    load(struct lottery array);
    printf("%d",array[0].aa);

    return 0;
}
```

Hello, I get an error at the line `load(struct lottery array);`
in my `main` function. The error says *Expected expression before struct*.
I googled it and I couldn't understand why would it expect an expression there and I am kinda confused.

Comment: Which line the error is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Please learn how to properly format the code. Readability is a major aspect of good code. :)

Comment: It seems to me that you need to [find a good beginners book about C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over.

Comment: @KevinDTimm ehh? isn't that the same as `array[i].aa`, seeing memory is allocated?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the function call. In your code, you've written

```
 load(struct lottery array);
```

which is wrong. You should pass only the variable as the argument, like

```
load(array);
```

That said, your `fopen()` failure check and subsequent code also looks wrong. You're checking for the failure case but continue to use the returned pointer anyway, which kinds of nullifies the effect of having the check in the first place.

Comment: @Edward  You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 1):

Parameters passed to functions when calling them are just variables - you don't need to include the data types as well. So the line

```
load(struct lottery array);
```

should just be

```
load(array);
```